# GRE 9768 #60 1. Does $(s+t)^2=s^2+t^2$ imply $s+s=0$? 2. Idempotent matrices do not form a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents, boolean-ring

[GRE 9768 #60](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967097) on what appears to be Boolean rings:

> [image]

[Ian Coley's approach](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%205%20solutions.pdf) is to prove $(I)$ and $(I) \implies (II) \implies (III)$

> [image]

---

1. I think $(II) \implies (I)$.  My attempt:

$$(s+t)^2=s^2+t^2 \iff s^2+st+ts+t^2=s^2+t^2 \iff st + ts = 0$$

By choosing $t=1$, we get $s+s=0$.

- Is this flawed because actually rings don't necessarily contain $1$ even though Algebra by Michael Artin defines that they do?
- What counterexamples does $(II) \implies (I)$ have if rings don't necessarily contain $1$ please? If none, then please prove $(II) \implies (I)$ for rings that don't necessarily contain $(1)$.

---

2. Am I right to say that collecting all idempotent matrices in $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ does not form a ring $R$ because if such collection were a ring, then it would be a Boolean ring and thus imply $A+A=0$ for all $A$ in $R$ which would imply $A=0$?

Comment: The sum of two idempotent matrices may not be idempotent, for example double an idempotent matrix.

Comment: @Joppy Right thanks, but in that case, we can view question 2  as about a different way of proving then, I guess.

Comment: I guess? But whenever you collect a subset of stuff together and want to call it a ring, the most obvious things to check are closure under addition and multiplication.

Comment: @Joppy Lol thanks. I'm [inelegant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896068). XD Post as answer? ^-^

Comment: @Joppy you can still post as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. From comments here: [How do I know the definition of rings or of anything on the GRE given that definitions can vary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967070)

> For the question about Boolean rings, this has been left unspecified, but a correct answer to the question will not need to assume the ring has a unit. – Joppy

2. From comments here: [GRE 9768 #60 Boolean rings: 1. Does $(s+t)^2=s^2+t^2$ imply $s+s=0$? 2. Idempotent matrices do not form a ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967052)

> The sum of two idempotent matrices may not be idempotent, for example double an idempotent matrix. – Joppy
>
> @Joppy Right thanks, but in that case, we can view question 2 as about a different way of proving then, I guess. – BCLC
>
> I guess? But whenever you collect a subset of stuff together and want to call it a ring, the most obvious things to check are closure under addition and multiplication. – Joppy
>
> @Joppy Lol thanks. I'm [inelegant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896068). XD Post as answer? ^-^ – BCLC 49 mins ago